# Using Axios to send form data

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, post, axios

Just wondering if it's possible to serialize data from a Html form element and then post the data using a post request with Axios.

Here is the code that shows the event that is fired when a button click occurs to submit the post.

```
function form_submission(e)
{
var data = document.getElementById('venueForm');

axios.post('/venue/', {


})
    .then (function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {

        console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Here is the html which shows how the data is selected

```
<form method="POST" action="http://core-site.test/venue/{{$venue->slug_field}}" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="venueForm">
```

Is serializing an option or do I have to set each value manually?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `FormData` class in JavaScript:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var data = new FormData(form);
axios.post('/example', data);
```

Comment: Give me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': parameter 1 is not of type 'HTMLFormElement'.